# Punctuation of dependent clauses with a common subject

Tags: punctuation, subjects, dependent-clause

I am wondering whether the following sentence is punctuated properly:

*From the previous section, the operator A is skew-adjoint; has compact resolvents; and thus has the required conditions.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. All the semicolons should be commas. See this wonderfully handy resource, [The Punctuation Guide.](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/semicolon.html)

Semicolons go

- Between independent clauses when a coordinating conjunction is
  omitted
- Between independent clauses linked by a transitional expression
- In lists with internal commas
- In elliptical constructions

This sentence doesn't contain any of these constructions.

It would still be an awkward sentence, though. It might be clearer like this:

"From the previous section, the operator A has the required conditions because it is skew-adjoint and has compact resolvents."